# Rails 4 cache not working with mongoid and can not expire from rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I found `caches_page` not working at all,

and fragment cache works, but still execute query, and can not be delete in rake file.

Why the cache in Rails is so painful.

Please help me

## controler

```
class City::MonthlyPriceController < CityController
  caches_page :index# not working at all , strange !!!

  def index
    sleep(30)
    QUERY_FROM_DB takes 30 seconds
  end
```

## index.html.haml # still executes cache even

```
- cache("index")  do
    = render "index_content"
```

## application.rb

```
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

## insert new data from csv every 10 minute in a rake file

```
action_controller = ActionController::Base.new
expire cache after inserting new data
action_controller.expire_page('/')
action_controller.expire_page('/city/monthly_price')
action_controller.expire_fragment("index")
```

## from the console i can get the query still executed

```
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
  MOPED: 0.0.0.0:27017 COMMAND      database=sample command={:aggregate=>"flights", :pipeline=>[{:$sort=>{:price=>1}}, $max_flight_date", :min_flight_date=>"$min_flight_date"}}]} runtime: 29.5010ms
  MOPED: 0.0.0.0:27017 QUERY        database=sample collection=flights selector={"$query"=>{"from"=>/.*.*/i, "to"=>/.*.*/i, "flight_date"=>{"$gte"=>2015-07-31 00:00:00 UTC, "$lte"=>2016-07-31 00:00:00 UTC}}, "$orderby"=>{"updated_at"=>-1}} flags=[] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 66.0380ms
  MOPED: 0.0.0.0:27017 GET_MORE     database=sample collection=flights limit=0 cursor_id=207362831332 runtime: 399.6380ms
  Cache digest for app/views/welcome/_historical_prices.html.haml: ff86f0f2a9c9bf0fe80613edea310d29
  Cache digest for app/views/common/_recently_changed_prices.html.haml: 772875622ff36375b2d84b67b76cf93b
```